# How to find all input elements with a given prefix within a div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a div with id ="propertiesDiv". It has certain input elements. All of them are text fields. Some of them have names like propertyName1, propertyName2 etc. I need to get all such inputs with names starting from "propertyName".

Below is code I have written so far but it gets me all inputs within that div.

```
$('#propertiesDiv').find('input').each(function(index, element){
    var name = element.name;
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're loking for jQuery's `starts with` selector ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/))

```
$('#propertiesDiv').find("input[name^='propertyName']")
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/zZYtj/

Comment: Just define a context - it's shorter: `$( 'input[name^="propertyName"]', '#propertiesDiv' )`

Comment: `[^=]` is not a jQuery selector, it's a common CSS3 selector

Comment: @Spadar, it might *also* be a CSS3 selector, but in this context, it is a jQuery selector.... as linked in the jQuery documentation!

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
$( 'input[name^="propertyName"]' , $('#propertiesDiv'))
```